# Gradle freezes on building react-native 0.60.3 for Android when applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings) is used

Tags: gradle, react-native, androidx

I upgraded our app to react-native 0.60.3 and it is working on iOS. Now that I am trying to build Android, I run into the following issue. When the following line is in my `settings.gradle

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

Gradle freezes building with the following output:

```
Initialized native services in: /Users/user/.gradle/native
Removing 0 daemon stop events from registry
Previous Daemon (13387) stopped at Thu Jul 18 15:53:51 PDT 2019 by user or operating system
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /Users/user/.gradle/daemon/5.4.1 Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.4.1-all/3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx/gradle-5.4.1/lib/gradle-launcher-5.4.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.4.1
Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
An attempt to start the daemon took 1.153 secs.
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 81885). The daemon log file: /Users/user/.gradle/daemon/5.4.1/daemon-81885.out.log
Starting build in new daemon [memory: 1.4 GB]
Using 12 worker leases.
Starting Build
<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [4m 0s]
> Evaluating settings
```

When I comment out `applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)` the build continues but fails further down the line because it can't find

```
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
...
List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
```

for dynamically generating my packages for autolinking.

My RN environment is:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.5
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Memory: 3.38 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 26, 27, 28
      Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.0, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
      System Images: android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-24 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
    Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: ^16.8.6 => 16.8.6
    react-native: ^0.60.3 => 0.60.3
  npmGlobalPackages:
    eslint-plugin-react-native: 3.5.0
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

A weird side effect that I have encountered is, that my react-native console sometimes doesn't terminate. When I ran the `react-native info` it prints out everything but doesn't terminate. Might be related or not.

This is my `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'app'
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
include ':instabug-reactnative'
project(':instabug-reactnative').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/instabug-reactnative/android')
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
include ':@react-native-community_netinfo'
project(':@react-native-community_netinfo').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android')
// include ':react-native-calendar-events'
// project(':react-native-calendar-events').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-calendar-events/android')
include ':react-native-adyen-cse'
project(':react-native-adyen-cse').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-adyen-cse/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':react-native-amplitude-analytics'
project(':react-native-amplitude-analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-amplitude-analytics/android')
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':amazon-cognito-identity-js'
project(':amazon-cognito-identity-js').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/android')
include ':react-native-geolocation-service'
project(':react-native-geolocation-service').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-geolocation-service/android')
include ':react-native-version-number'
project(':react-native-version-number').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-version-number/android')
include ':react-native-app-settings'
project(':react-native-app-settings').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-app-settings/android')
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
include ':react-native-fast-image'
project(':react-native-fast-image').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fast-image/android')
include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')
include ':react-native-i18n'
project(':react-native-i18n').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-i18n/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':app'
include ':react-native-fabric'
project(':react-native-fabric').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fabric/android')
include ':react-native-version-check'
project(':react-native-version-check').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,    '../node_modules/react-native-version-check/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

and my `MainApplication.java`:

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {

    private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
            List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
            // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
            // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            return packages;
        }
    };

    protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
        return mCallbackManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Answers(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete node modules, do npm install and react-native link